# Submitting AMPscript functions following submit?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is it possible to have an AMPscript function only execute following the submission of a form?

For example, we have a Web Collect code that is unsubscribing a user from a list through Web Collect functionality. Ideally, we want to update a field in a Data Extension at the same time - but this will only be reflected once they've submitted their subscriber / unsubscribe status. How can I make sure that the Data Extension is only updated after they've submitted, as opposed to running once the page is loaded?

I've tried moving the function into a javascript function that is called after the submit, but it is still running once the form is loaded. I also cannot think of any AMPscript variable I can use to create an ELSE/IF statement that would help.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but not with Web Collect.

You'll have to build the form in AMPScript (or SSJS) using the [API functions](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/api_ampscript_functions/) and have it post to itself or another page that does the work.

Since AMPScript and SSJS are server-side only, they only get processed a page-load.